# smoke smell from the chimney/fireplace?

Tags: cleaning

With woodstove removed and not being reinstalled, how do we get rid of the burned wood smell in the fireplace/chimney?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you've just got to roll up your sleeves and go to work...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Negative air pressure in the house draws air down the chimney.

Cap the chimney so it's airtight at the top.

Not sure whether this is a masonry fireplace with ceramic tile liner or multiwall metal stack, but the following helps.

They make blow up vinyl balloon type devices for completely blocking airflow lower in the chimney. Fireplace dampers are notoriously leaky if that's still installed, it may have been cut out if this is a fireplace insert conversion.

As the other answer indicates, sweep it out, the smell is worst in creosote (partially burned volatiles) and less in soot (carbon black). I guarantee that the acrid smell from what's penetrated into chimney tile will linger for a couple years though. A good stiff brushing will clear out most metal chimney liners and vastly attenuate the smell.